# A Miners Future

Tags: mining-theory, mining-hardware

I want to support the Monero network and eventually fill a warehouse with miners.  Will there ever be a point where the reward for mining is no longer justifiable?  For example, before BitCoin split, there was a lot of news saying not to mine BitCoin coins because the time it took mine is not worth the reward.

Edit:
Setting aside block reward and money, would/could there be a time when it is no longer possible to mine enough shares to get a coin daily?

Edit 2:
I would be mining in a pool. The idea is to buy a high end PC and do GPU mining, use the money from that Miner to buy another miner, then repeat until I have to buy a building to store and run my miners. I'm looking for the long term investment. I don't have two coins to rub together. I'm not worried that it could take years, I would like to know if in 5 or 10 years that mining will still be valued and easy as it is today.

Thank you,

Comment: This is fundamentally unknowable, since it is essentially asking about the future price of monero. I will vote to close this, but one salient point is that the monero block reward will not drop below the equivalent of 0.3 monero per minute (independent of any fees on top), so there's a floor. Whether the monero price makes it worthwhile for a miner, though, depends on what the future brings.

Comment: Your edit still does not include enough information to answer the question (will you join a pool, or solo mine?). Based on the current hash rate, the estimated time it will take for you (or your pool) to find a block is just a simple division problem. Future network hash rates are unknown